# How is the specific impulse of a gridded ion thruster derived?

Tags: rocket-science, propulsion, ions

How is the specific impulse of a gridded ion thruster derived?

I've searched and got a variety of answers and Bard gives a different answer each time I ask it.

Too the best that I can reckon it's:

1/9.8 * sqrt(2 * (mass/current) * voltage)